# How to echo with out \n \t \r in php?

Tags: php, html, mysql

In my code this select :

```
<select name="TutorName">
        <?php
        while ($tutor = mysql_fetch_array($resultTutor, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $tutor['TutorPrefix'];?> 
                        <?php echo $tutor['TutorFirstName'];?> 
                        <?php echo $tutor['TutorLastName'];?>">
                        <?php echo $tutor['TutorPrefix'];?> 
                        <?php echo $tutor['TutorFirstName'];?> 
                        <?php echo $tutor['TutorLastName'];?> </option>

        <?php
        }
        ?>
        </select>
```

The problem is I get this result in html

```
"TutorName":"Dr. \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\tSafaa \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\tNassar",
```

How can I join them in one line with out \r\n\t

I have try this and it not work

```
<?php echo $tutor['TutorPrefix']$tutor['TutorFirstName']$tutor['TutorLastName'];?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php echo "$tutor[TutorPrefix]$tutor[TutorFirstName]$tutor[TutorLastName]";?>
```

Mind the quotes.

Alternatively you may use this approach:

```
while ($tutor = mysql_fetch_array($resultTutor, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $input = "<option value='$tutor[TutorPrefix] 
                    $tutor[TutorFirstName] 
                    $tutor[TutorLastName]'>
                    $tutor[TutorPrefix] 
                    $tutor[TutorFirstName] 
                    $tutor[TutorLastName]'
              </option>";
    //Do some processing according to the other answers
    echo removeunwantedcharcters($input);
}
```

Comment: This work `value="<?php echo $tutor['TutorPrefix'];?> <?php echo $tutor['TutorFirstName'];?> <?php echo $tutor['TutorLastName'];?>">`

Answer (score 2):

```
echo $tutor['TutorPrefix'].$tutor['TutorFirstName'].$tutor['TutorLastName'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$cleanString = trim($strname, "\t");
```

to remove unwanted characters from strings.

See the php docs [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

Comment: Unless he puts the HTML code into an actual string variable, this solution won't do him any good.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
$output = str_replace(array("\r","\n","\t"), "", $input);
```

also try with this

```
$regex = '/(\s|\\\\[rntv]{1})/';
$output = preg_replace($regex, '', $input);
```

Comment: That won't solve his particular problem, because the \r\n\t characters aren't in his datasets, but rather in his HTML.

Comment: They will............try

Comment: Not unless the HTML code is first put into a string variable. In this context however, it's directly output to the browser. I never claimed the code was faulty.